# C# client server chat

Tags: c#, server, client, chat

I learn how to make a simple client server chat on c#.
I did a small project and i really need to host the server side code on some server that support c# ,on my local machine it works fine.

Please,
How can i do this?whats my options?

Comment: Check this out: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/

Answer (score 0):

You will need an iis server aka windows server. İf you don't want to physically host Azure is a good option if not there are many VM providers of Windows servers